# Maven project depends on Maven projects two levels down

Tags: java, maven

I have a project, my-project, that has a submodule, wala.  Wala in turn has several sub-projects.  Like this:

```
my-project
| pom.xml
| wala
  | pom.xml
  | wala.foo
    | pom.xml
  | wala.bar
    | pom.xml
  | wala.baz
    | pom.xml
```

my-project only depends on wala.foo and wala.baz and does not depend on wala.bar.  In fact, wala.bar has build problems currently that are beyond my control.

Is there a way that my-project/pom.xml can depend on wala.foo and wala.baz without depending on wala.bar?

Comment: I looked at that link, but I still don't see how to do it, given that the modules I don't want to build are two levels down.  I want to avoid editing wala/pom.xml if I can and only edit my-project/pom.xml.

Comment: Look at the second answer: it uses the `-pl !<module_name>` notation that would work here. Something like `mvn -pl !wala.bar clean install`

Comment: So you have to do it on the command-line?  It's not possible to do it solely within my-project/pom.xml?

Comment: I must be missing something, can't you just rearrange your directories so that wala.foo and wala.baz are the sub-modules of my-project, and change my-project's pom.xml to reflect that?